# Defining dimensions of box image loads in?

Tags: html

On my website, whilst images are loading a square appears until the image has loaded.

**I want the loading space to be the same size as the image that will load?**

*(Im struggling to define the images in pixels because the images are currently defined in percentages)*

here is my code currently -

```html
<style type="text/css">ul{
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }
        ul li{
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
        }
        ul li a{
            display: block;
            padding: 0px 0px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        ul li a:hover{
        }
        ul li ul.dropdown{
            min-width: 125px; /* Set width of the dropdown */
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 999;
            left: 0;
        }
        ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
            display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
        }
        ul li ul.dropdown li{
            display: block;
        }
</style>
<style type="text/css">.video-container {
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom:56.25%;
 padding-top:0px;
 height:0;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
</style>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;" summary="main">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
   <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 80%;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td width="12.5%"><a href="https://www.oymyo.com"><img onmouseout="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/o.png'" onmouseover="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/o.gif'" src="https://www.oymyo.com/images/o.png" width="50px" /></a></td>
      <td width="12.5%"><a href="https://www.oymyo.com/about"><img onmouseout="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_about.png'" onmouseover="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_about2.png'" src="https://www.oymyo.com/images/_about.png" width="100px" /></a></td>
      <td width="12.5%"><a href="https://www.oymyo.com/store"><img onmouseout="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_store.png'" onmouseover="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_store2.png'" src="https://www.oymyo.com/images/_store.png" width="100px" /></a></td>
      <td width="12.5%"><a href="https://www.oymyo.com/news"><img onmouseout="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_news.png'" onmouseover="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_news2.png'" src="https://www.oymyo.com/images/_news.png" width="100px" /></a></td>
      <td width="12.5%"><a href="https://www.oymyo.com/art"><img onmouseout="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_art.png'" onmouseover="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_art2.png'" src="https://www.oymyo.com/images/_art.png" width="100px" /></a></td>
      <td width="12.5%"><a href="https://www.oymyo.com/fashion"><img onmouseout="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_fashion.png'" onmouseover="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_fashion2.png'" src="https://www.oymyo.com/images/_fashion.png" width="100px" /></a></td>
      <td width="12.5%"><a href="https://www.oymyo.com/support.php"><img onmouseout="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_support.png'" onmouseover="this.src='https://www.oymyo.com/images/_support2.png'" src="https://www.oymyo.com/images/_support.png" width="100px" /></a></td>
      <td width="12.5%">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="https://www.oymyo.com/images/_extras.png" width="100px" /></a>
       <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="https://www.oymyo.com/aiyu.html"><img src="https://www.oymyo.com/images/_aiyu.png" width="100px" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.oymyo.com/babycakes"><img src="https://www.oymyo.com/images/_babycakes.png" width="100px" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.oymyo.com/xxcx"><img src="https://www.oymyo.com/images/_xxcx.png" width="100px" /></a></li>
       </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

this is how the page currently looks whilst loading;
https://www.OYMYO.com/images/stackoverflow_image_loading.png

this is how i want the page to look whilst loading;
- https://www.OYMYO.com/images/stackoverflow_image_desired.png

any help would be greatly appreciated [: